# My Google Maps custom overlays are not "active" anymore in Chrome and Firefox, but work fine in IE

Tags: maps, overlay

Since a couple of months, my custom overlays appear to be disabled.

They are still visible and displayed correctly, but the link does not work anymore, nor does the CSS that changes `z-index`. They just seem to be drawn, and that's it.

The link is there, but I can't click it.

This happened in Chrome and Firefox, not in IE.

Has anyone had similar issues? I've searched and searched the web again and again, nothing. However I'm sure I must've missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally figured it out: wrong overlay layer. One is specifically dedicated to mouse events: overlayMouseTarget